# rspec: how to tell rspec to test the first n contexts of a file and quit

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

Just as the title says.

I tend to add five tests at a time. I want rspec to stop processing after the fifth

```
context "fdsfsd"
end
```

block.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just tag the tests   you want to run.  I usually use the wip tag for work in progress.  That way, I just run rspec on that tag.